# Units in UV Editor (Imperial to Metric)

Tags: units

as per title, is it possible during image export and during editing to use the metric unit system instead of the default imperial system in the UV editor window

I'm using blender 2.80.44 Beta (this question also applies to previous version, i have the same issue there too)

thank you guys (and girls)

Answer (score 3):

In the UV editor the units are either pixels (default is a 256 x 256 pixel square) or when Normalized is checked the square is 0.0 to 1.0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, i forgot about the normalizing option, i was actually talking about when click export UV Layout option

Comment: This is the official accepted answer, do not down vote, thanks.