# UV Editor - Use other Units of measurements

Tags: uv-image-editor, units

This is a follow up to my previous question (related, not a duplicate): [Units in UV Editor (Imperial to Metric)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132277/units-in-uv-editor-imperial-to-metric)

I would like to use:

- Inches
- cm
- mm
- m

During the creation or export phase:
[image]

So I won't have to do conversions from a unit to pixels.

if there is no option yet, I'll do the below then. - Thanks

**I'll look the dev repo on github and will make a pull request.**

- To support: cm, mm, m, km, inches, feet/foot, yards.

Comment: Unwrap space is not directly related to scene coordinates. UVs introduce distortions, so you can't unequivocally map scene units to UVs

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos you are mistaken, its not scene coordinates, its the input field only.

so this will get the the screen dpi (dots per inch)
1 inch = 2.54 cm
dpi = 96 px / inch
96 px / 2.54 cm

Therefore one centimeter is equal to
1 cm = 96 px / 2.54
1 cm = 38 px for 96 dpi.

so this if the inputs are:
1cm, it will get the screens current dpi then divide by 2.54 and multiple that result by the the input of 1cm or whatever cm.

pixels = RoundUp(input * (dpi / 2.54))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This doesn't exist yet.

**I will be submitting a pull request to the Blender3D Repo for version 2.80+**

*It will allow you to enter:*

- MM, CM, M, KM, Inches, Foot/Feet and Yards

> with a screen DPI of 96 DPI
> it will take input: 20cm
>
> and it will output: 756px

Using this formula:

- dpi = current monitor/screen or blenders dpi setting
- scale = getScaleFromInputField() * 2.54
- pixels = RoundUp(input * (dpi / scale))

getScaleFromInputField will convert MM, M, KM, Inches, Foot/Feet and Yards To Centimeters and return the correct value

Using this conversion chart:
[image]

You can contribute to my repo: https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can select scene unit at "Scene" panel (Blender 2.79b) but for the new texture setting it's unavailable yet.

[image]

BTW I don't think the unit "cm/m" makes any sense for texturing because the images are used on the basis of modeling, instead of printing... Meanwhile there're other factors that can influence width/height, dpi/ppi for example. Nah, that was my subjective idea.

Comment: well lets say you want to set the size of a image to be 1m by 1m with the correct uv gird when exporting it.

this would allow you to edit quickly and also enter real world sizes without conversion charts

Comment: also dpi can be changed when you edit the texture in an editor like photoshop

Comment: this just makes it that most of the work is done, also no guess work involved

Comment: also in 2.80 (as per question) this metric for the UV is missing (unless it hidden away, i've checked all panels and tabs, and also the prefs)